# Setting a Gtk::ComboBoxText to non editable

Tags: c++, gtkmm

how would I set a Gtk::ComboBoxText to non-editable, what I mean here is there may be say 10 selections in the combo box to choose from how can I make it so your simply not allowed to choose something other than the text I have set it to?
(this question does not relate to my putting a Gtk::Entry into a combo box and making that non editable, or something like that)

Comment: You want to disable the whole combobox?  Or disable specific entries in the combobox?  The former is simply a `set_sensitive(false)` call (https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a3192b5f7f4c15876169b913eb9d1075e), the latter is more involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set_sensitive(false) fixed everything